Zabbix 6.4 active check is unknown while passive monitoring is active
edit: Problem resolved, see comments
I have a problem with active monitoring on Zabbix. I set up my lab as follows:

Zabbix 6.4 (172.16.16.106) on Ubuntu Server 22.04
Windows Server 2022 (172.16.16.166)
both machines are in the same network
in the network there is a Sophos Firewall with IP 172.16.16.254

and connected Windows Server to Zabbix. As far as I can see, the passive monitoring is working as intended, but the active monitoring shows me the status "unknown":
enter image description here
In zabbix_agentd.conf the configuration I edited:
ServerActive=172.16.16.106
Hostname=Zabbix server
After restarting Zabbix services agent on Windows, Windows doesn't show specific logs, but Active Checks status is still unknown:
  9032:20240423:155856.369 using configuration file: C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.conf
  9032:20240423:155856.896 agent #0 started [main process]
  9064:20240423:155856.898 agent #1 started [collector]
  8008:20240423:155856.901 agent #2 started [listener #1]
  5300:20240423:155856.902 agent #3 started [listener #2]
  7336:20240423:155856.903 agent #4 started [listener #3]
  8288:20240423:155856.904 agent #5 started [active checks #1]

I checked the Windows Server 2022 firewall and there is a rule for inbound port 10050. I can ping both systems from the other one.
Does somebody any idea, how to activate active check?

It worked after I changed Hostname=Zabbix server to Hostname=
